# Jimp: How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property of 'lineHeight' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use jimp to add text to an image. Where am I going wrong in the print function to receive this error.

```
let fileName = 'botImageTemplate.png';
let fontPerson = Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_128_BLACK).then(font => font);
Jimp.read(fileName)
  .then(image => {
    return image
    .print(fontPerson, 50, 50, {
      text: "This is my text",
      alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
      alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_MIDDLE
    }, 40, 40)
    .write('botTesting.png')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

The error message I keep getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property of 'lineHeight' of undefined"

What do I have to change to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know jimp, but can you try to add arguments:   maxWidth and maxHeight.
For me it seems there are missing some properies.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp